# iOS how to segue a selected cell value into another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I have a Uitableview cell that has been successfully populated with dictionary array. Right now, i have difficulty passing the selected cell value to another view controller and display that value.

Here is my codes:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    NSLog(@"Tapped: %@",[[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"IncidentNumber"]);
    someProperty = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"IncidentNumber"];
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"item" sender:self];

}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yourSegue"])
    {

        DescriptionViewController *vc;
               vc = segue.destinationViewController;

                vc.item_pass = someProperty;
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the difficulty? Are you resetting value of item_pass in `viewdidLoad` of your destination view controller?

Comment: what is the issue ? where did u delcare the some property ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you perform a segue with the identifier **item** but later in `prepareForSegue` you check for a segue with the identifier **yourSegue**...

Comment: Mr.T said it. Good catch!

Comment: i should buy a magnifying glass tomorrow!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` connect the segue to the table view cell (rather than to the view controller).

Then the selected cell is passed as `sender` parameter in `prepareForSegue` and you can get the index path with

```
let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)!
```